# Push found items into an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a functioning php+mysql connection in which items from the mysql  are searched for through a search box (utilizing *typeahead.min.js*) in the php.

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","USDA");
$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from mytable where Foods LIKE '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $array[] = $row['Foods'];
}
echo json_encode($array);
mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

I want to insert an *"ADD"* button underneath the search box. This *"ADD"* button does two things: (1) adds the found item to an array and (2) restores the search box.

Comment: This code is _wide_ open to sql injection attacks. Please read about the benefits of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Comment: While this search implementation probably works it is extremely inefficient. The moment your database grows over non trivial size this will stop being usable.

Comment: About the "ADD" button: so what is your actual question here? You currently only state that you want something. Fine. If so then what is your question?

Comment: arkascha, thanks for your response.

Comment: @arkascha, (1) for the security of the page, I will be working on it. (2) About the efficiency of the method, this is what I have found with very limited experience, I would appreciate it if you could suggest a better strategy for achieving the same goal. (3) For the "ADD" button, the question was how to implement it  and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this multiple ways, when the form has been processed (you are searching and it is successful) you can store the result ID or Name or Both or whatever info you need in either

```
$_SESSION
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

or

```
$_COOKIES
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Being new you should research these 2 as you will more than likely need to use then again. You should also prepare your statements for mysqli to help stay safe against attacks.

Prepared Statements
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: This does not in any way answer the question about an "ADD button underneath the search box". It makes some general remarks, so it should have been a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help.